# SQL query not returning results when combining collate and escape function using mutated vowels (umlauts)

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping, collate

I have a query just like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
WHERE name COLLATE BINARY_AI LIKE '%ög%' ESCAPE '\';
```

The expected behavior would be that it returns names containing `ög`, like:

`Högendorf`

But, for example, also names containing just `og`, like:

`Vogel`

However, executing this query doesn't deliver a single result.
For reference, the data type of name is CHAR(30)

If I slightly change it to use `'%og%'` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
WHERE name COLLATE BINARY_AI LIKE '%og%' ESCAPE '\';
```

It suddenly works and delivers the results as expected.
It also does so if I keep the `'%ög%'` but remove the `ESCAPE '\'` part of the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM table
WHERE name COLLATE BINARY_AI LIKE '%ög%';
```

If I remove the `COLLATE BINARY_AI` but leave the `ESCAPE '\'` instead, it works, but it doesn't find results like `Vogel`

And if I add a second `COLLATE BINARY_AI` to the `'%ög%'`, it also doesn't return any results at all.

Why does this happen, and how could I fix this so I could keep the ESCAPE function?

Comment: I am able to reproduce this behavior. It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I'm not a oracle specialist, does changing it to a nchar help?  Also, technically, isn't 'o' different to 'ö'?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's not right!

This is fixed in the [Oracle Database 23c Free](https://www.oracle.com/database/free/) release:

```
select banner_full from v$version;

BANNER_FULL                                                                                                                                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 23c Free Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Develop, Learn, and Run for Free
Version 23.3.0.23.09

create table t (
  c1 varchar2(30)
);
insert into t values ( 'Högendorf' );
insert into t values ( 'Vogel' );

select * from t
where  c1 collate binary_ai like '%ög%' escape '\';

C1                            
------------------------------
Högendorf
Vogel
```

If you need a fix for this, speak with support.